# Logged in admin, can't see front end site when system is off

Tags: system-status

This just started happening. When I am logged in as admin and system status was off I could still see the front end. Now I can't. I need to set the system status to on in order to see the front end. This isn't ideal for development. Any thoughts?

Comment: You tagged this with Craft 3... are you seeing this on the Craft 3 dev preview? https://craftcms.com/3 Or is it on Craft 2.x?

Comment: Oh ya it's not craft 3

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this on the latest Craft 2.x release.  You sure you're logged in as an admin? Maybe you're tested on a different subdomain? (www vs. non-www)?

Comment: That might have been it. It seems to be working now. I'm not entirely sure what I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by adding a redirect to get rid of the www. The issue was my admin would be www but the front end wasn't.